# Lua Least Common Multiple Program Not Enough Memory

Tags: loops, lua, out-of-memory, infinite-loop

This is a Lua program I wrote to find the least common multiple of two numbers. When I run it, it asks for two numbers as intended, but when it tries to run them through the function, it runs out of memory.

```
function lcm(a,b)
    aList={}
    bList={}
    c=0
        if a<b then
            repeat
                c=c+1
                aList[c]=a*c
                bList[c]=b*c
                aL=table.getn(aList)
            until aL==b
            else
            if a>b then
                repeat
                    c=c+1
                    aList[c]=a*c
                    bList[c]=b*c
                    bL=table.getn(bList)
                until bL==a
            end
        end
    e=1
    repeat
        d=1
        repeat
            if aList[e]==bList[d] then
                f=aList[e]
                return f
            end
        d=d+1
        until d==table.getn(aList)
    e=e+1
    until e==table.getn(bList)
end

n1=io.read()
n2=io.read()
ans=lcm(n1,n2)
print(ans)
```

Comment: Using `repeat ... until` to iterate over lists is very non-idiomatic

Comment: Also, you've got an off by one error somewhere - `lcm(3, 5)` returns nil. As does `lcm(3, 3)`

Comment: [Here's](https://gist.github.com/eric-wieser/9923fe959cf2d50e4f8a) the same (incorrect) algorithm, written idiomatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug arises because of the `io.read` call. From [PiL](http://www.lua.org/pil/21.1.html)

> The read function reads strings from the current input file.

Thus, your values `n1` and `n2` are passed as strings inside the function and hence, never causing the `until aL == b` or `until bL == a` to be satisfied as one of them is a **string** another a **number**. To solve this problem, you can one of the following:

1. Pass `"*number"` as control argument:

   ```
   n1 = io.read( "*number" )
   n2 = io.read( "*number" )
   ```
2. Cast `a` and `b` to numbers:

   ```
   function lcm(a,b)
       a, b = tonumber(a), tonumber(b)
   ```

Comment: @user2604809 You can thank him by clicking that green checkmark